# Github action - Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

**tsconfig.json**

```
   "types": [
      "node",
      "Multer"
    ]
```

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.9",
}
```

On github it gives an error during npm run build

**workflow.yaml**

```
        # Downloads a copy of the code in your repository before running CI tests
        - name: Check out repository code
          uses: actions/checkout@v3

        # Performs a clean installation of all dependencies in the package.json file
        # For more information, see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html
        - name: Install dependencies
          run: npm ci

        - name: Build
          run: npm run build
```

Secondly this error also appears during building production image

**Dockerfile**

```
RUN npm install --production
RUN npm install -g @nestjs/cli
RUN npm run build
```

Answer (score 1):

@types/multer has @types/express as a dependancy. You should install @types/express also if you haven't allready.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).